# How to pass an object array to graphql

Tags: spring-boot, graphql

I am working on graphql, how to pass an array of object to the graphql type schema.
for example:
expect output:

```
[
  {
    "color": "red",
    "owners": [
       {
          "ownerName":"Rob",
          "ownerOcupation": "teacher"
        }
  }
```

]

my schema:

```
...
type Query {
   allCars:[Car]}

type Car {
color:String
owners: [owner]
 }

type owner {
 ownerName: String
 ownerOcupation: String
 }
```

car entity:

```
@Column
private String color;
@OneToMany
private List <owner> owners;

owner entity:
@Column
private String ownerName;
@Column
private String ownerOcupation;
```

it doesn't display the owners section as expected. How should I pass the owner into the owners in the car?

Comment: If there's something wrong with your code, it's impossible to debug without seeing the code itself. Please edit your question to include the relevant code.

Comment: my question is if this is the correct way to pass an object array in the graphql schema

Comment: show your `resolvers` and/or `entity model`, its where you should write logic for this feature

Comment: update the post and add entity model

Comment: Could you show the actual result, what does it mean `doesn't display as expected`?